# Best Sellers Report

Tags: magento2, database, best-seller

I am having issues where not all items are showing the bestseller block in the admin dashboard.

I have narrowed this down to the sales_order_item table.

If a product is bought through the frontend it is set as product_type 'grouped' in the sales_order_item table but 'simple' in the quote_item table.

If an item is bought through adminhtml then both are 'simple' and the product shows as a bestseller.

The fixes I am considering need to do either:

1. Make sure items arent set as 'grouped' in sales_order_item table
2. Allow grouped items in the bestseller block

Any ideas how to do either?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the end I decided to write a preference for the Resource Model to allow grouped products into the bestsellers report.